# sqlite3 doesn't retrieve data from table

Tags: database, sqlite

I verified that table exists with

> .tables;

but when I try to retrieve data from selected table, it doesn't show anything, like so:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM films;
sqlite>
```

it just passes me to execute another command...

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It returned 0 rows.
One thing you can do to reassure you:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM films;
```